Why is Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_ID -Properties memberof missing one AD group?
Can the script#1 be fixed to correctly show all the AD groups for users, similar to script#2 ?
The script#1 display only one AD group:
$AD_ID="YOUR AD SAM"
$AD_user=Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_ID  -Properties memberof
$AD_groups=($AD_user.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';
$AD_groups.Count
$AD_groups

==== Result for above script ======
1
DM

However, The script#2 correctly displays all the AD groups :
$AD_ID="YOUR AD SAM"
$AD_groups=Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $AD_ID | sort name
$AD_groups.Count
$Groups_In_String=";"
$GroupSize=$AD_groups.Count-1
for ($j=0;$j -le $GroupSize; $j++)
{ $Groups_In_String=$Groups_In_String+$AD_groups.Item($j).name+";"}
$Groups_In_String

====== Result for above script ======
2
;DM;Domain Users;

I would like to learn why script#1 cannot produce the same result as script#2

Your question is very confusing and badly formatted but for the question as to why script1 produces a different result, I assume you mean due to the count of AD Groups. The reason is -join ';' which will join all elements of an array by the specified delimiter and will output a single string and a single string is 1 element.

Thank you for  your quick reply. The "-join" in my code has no affect in the count of AD groups. I removed it and the result still missing one AD group for any given AD user. By the way, the formatting of my post  looks  perfect to me now. Thanks to whoever corrected it.

Ahhh so your question is why the count discrepancy, and that is probably because .MemberOf doesn't include the user's PrimaryGroup so basically, $AD_user=Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_ID  -Properties memberof, PrimaryGroup then $AD_user.memberof + $AD_user.PrimaryGroup | % { .... should give you the same count. If that answers your question let me know and I'll post an answer

@Santiago Squarzon. Thank you very much. Your suggestion worked and now I understand what the issue was.  I updated the script#1 with your suggestion:
                                                                                                                                    ` $AD_ID="My AD SAM"

$AD_user=Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_ID  -Properties memberof ,PrimaryGroup
$AD_groups=$AD_user.memberof +$AD_user.PrimaryGroup;  `

As explained in comments, the reason for the Count discrepancy between Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership and .MemberOf is because the .MemberOf collection will not contain the user's PrimaryGroup (usually Domain Users).
So, if you want to use the first approach in your code you could simply query the user's PrimaryGroup in addition to MemberOf and then concatenate the values, however you should note that this approach will fail as soon as the user is a member of a group in a different domain.
$AD_ID = 'YOUR AD SAM'
$AD_user = Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_ID -Properties Memberof, PrimaryGroup
$AD_groups = ($AD_user.MemberOf + $AD_user.PrimaryGroup | Get-ADGroup).Name -join ';'
$AD_groups.Count
$AD_groups

